# Offline packages are not being installed in google translate????

Tags: google-translate

I downloaded the offline packages in translate app. It is still displayed as "installing" but installation didnt complete from nearly 6 months

Answer (score 0):

I did restart the phone before that and cleared the system cache files.

It was still rotating and saying "Installing".

I pressed the button to stop the installing process. Then I selected to download the language again and it worked. Done. Hope it helps in your case too.

Similar question is in here - [offline packages not downloading in google translate](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/197207/how-to-fix-the-problem-of-offline-packages-not-downloading-in-google-translate), resolved by cache cleaning or turning off VPN, although I didn't have the Download Manager described in there on my Huawei P10 lite with Android 8 and EMUI 8.

Comment: Thank your for the reference  sir